# Should default values be mentioned by the getter or setter Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

What is the convention for documenting the default values of optional properties?

When a class contains an optional property with a getter and a setter method, should the default value be specified by the getter or setter method? Or Both?

When users stop and ask themselves "wait... what happens if I don't set this value?" which method will they look at first?

Here is a concrete example:

```
public interface JsonLoader
{
  /**
   * @param verify true if the returned JSON should be verified
   */
  void setVerify(boolean verify);

  /**
   * @return true if the returned JSON should be verified
   */
  boolean getVerify();

  /**
   * Loads the JSON file.
   * @throws VerificationException if the JSON was invalid
   */
  String load() throws VerificationException;
}
```

In the above code, where am I expected to specify that "verify" is true by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Builder pattern usually doesn't have getters (resulting in a fluent API), since the idea is to set the required values and build the resulting object.

Even the wikipedia examples *you* linked don't have getters.

Otherwise speaking there is no *specified* place to have the default values, so I'd recommend looking at other APIs to see what choice they have done and choosing something that's pleasing to your eye.

It doesn't really even matter, as long as it's documented *somewhere* in the Javadoc. If you're in the right class, you'll find it even if it might not be in the first place you imagine. The javadocs aren't that big after all.

In your example code *I* would expect that the default value be `false` if not said otherwise, but if it weren't (or even if it were) that it would be mentioned at least in the setter. But again, there's no rule and you see all kinds of customs.

Comment: I removed the referenced to the builder pattern. My question was generally speaking is ... when you have getter/setters for a property, which one (or both?) should specify the default value in the Javadoc?

Comment: “as long as it's documented *somewhere*” is the right answer, but it’s worth emphasizing the existence of `@see` tags. Besides that, I think it’s a flaw of javadoc that it can’t group getters and setters together, as that would eliminate a lot of redundant documentation…

Answer (score 0):

There is not set rule that a class needs to have getters and setters. But, the basic idea of a class is to create objects out of it. A class is just like a blueprint. The object is the one you build with the blueprint. The object needs to have some properties. If the class does not have a setter method, there is no use of the object you are building with it. Similarly, if you need to use the property of that object, you need a getter. You might not need anyone of them but not both of them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe this is answering my question. I am not asking when/if I need a getter or setter method. I am asking where should I document the default value of the property they are associated with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about getters and setters, you're not discussing construction. I'd expect some sort of constructor, initializing your object to a valid state. That should take care of it, and documentation should be put there. Possibly with multiple constructors.

If you're using the builder patter, it should be added to the `build()` or `construct()` method, since it should verify and create the desired object.

If you're having a DTO, then it should have a constructor, or a builder. Getters and setters is usually not proper design.

If, however, you want to do something like that, I'd add getters with default values, *and call them as such*, i.e. `getBananaWithDefault()`, or `getDefaultedBanana()`, and not expose the plain getters (or have the getters have a different name as well)

In the example for interfaces, I would document as follows:

```
/**
 * if the returned JSON should be verified
 */
void setVerify(boolean setVerifying);

/**
 * @return whether the JSON should be verified
 */
boolean getVerify();

/**
 * Loads the JSON file.
 * Will default to use verification if not set
 * @throws VerificationException if verification is enabled and the JSON is invalid
 */
String load() throws VerificationException;
```

But that's my personal opinion. I might even forgo the setVerify & getVerify and only have a `disableVerification()` method

Comment: So, in the builder pattern you would specify all the defaults in the `build()` method? That might be a long list of defaults if you have many properties... What would you do for non-builder patterns like the example I've included in the updated question?

Comment: Updated my response.